# Bitbucket monitoring using Grafana & Prometheus

Tags: bitbucket, prometheus, monitoring, grafana

Which Bitbucket metrics should be monitored using Grafana and Prometheus, and why?

FYI: Our Bitbucket server is up in a dockerised infra